# Core Data (SQLite backed) custom sorting of strings

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

I currently have a SQLite backed Core Data app where I am fetching records sorted on firstName and then lastName.

The issue is that I have some names like `(John Doe)` and they are coming back at the top of the list, it seems the default sorting behavior is done in ASCII sort order.

Is there anyway to force these records to show up after `Z`?

I have read about custom sort descriptors but they do not seem to work because Core Data falls back on SQLite for sorting.

**Update**

Here is a sample list of what my data looks like now

```
(Abe Simpson)
(Bob Dole)
(Chris Rock)
Alan West
Brian Regan
```

What I want it to look like

```
Alan West
Brian Regan
(Abe Simpson)
(Bob Dole)
(Chris Rock)
```

Comment: what do you want, need to put some records at end forcely without any short basis. I dont think this (John Doe) comes at last after z by the sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new BOOL attribute called `parenthesized`, then...

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    [self setPrimitiveName:name];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    self.parenthesized = ([name hasPrefix:@"("] &&
                          [name hasSuffix:@")"]);
}
```

And when you do the fetch:

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"parenthesized" ascending:NO],
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES],
  nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this approach worked perfect for me. One side note for anyone looking at this in the future, if parenthesized is a BOOL set ascending to YES in the sort descriptor for them to show up at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason for the parenthesis ? You could probably make things easier for yourself if you replaced this implicit information with explicit information in a separate property that can then be used to direct sorting

Comment: It is how a customer stores/segments some of their data (not a great approach), it is essentially out of my control though short of stripping the parenthesis which they do not want. I suppose I could add some kind of flag to the record that tells it to show at the bottom of the list or something...

Comment: Actually Daniels solutions looks good, it gives you the best of both worlds

Answer (score 0):

Read up on custom collations in SQLite. You probably do not have access to them on the i-devices though.

Comment: It seems Core Data does not allow custom collations

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a really simple answer/solution.  This works for me locally (not on an iPhone).

```
order by replace(firstName, '(','')
```

After reading back over your post, you wanted them to be at the bottom.  The above would sort them as if the parenthesis were ignored.  Below would get the output you wanted (although seems somewhat hackish).

```
order by replace(firstName, '(','ZZZ')
```

Comment: jsuggs, I am not accessing SQLite directly with SQL statements, I am using Core Data to handle the fetching. Thank you though

Comment: Ahh, so no ability to sent a sort parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately not in that way, at least not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

when you do the core data fetch, you get an array back, sort the array using the- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator
 method. you can then write your own sorting method which returns NSOrderAscending if the element is earlier, NSOrderDescending if it is later, and NSOrderSame if its the same.

Comment: I am using NSFetchedResultsController for efficiency as I have a potentially large number of records. I cannot load the entire result set into an NSArray and use this method of sorting.

Comment: in that case options are to stop using NSFetchedResultsController, or possibly split these elements out into another entity, I would lean towards the first, but you will have to be very careful about passing notifications on about context changes.