# Using a predicate with the aggregate operator IN with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

If I were to use a predicate with the IN operator for fetching results using Core Data:

```
NSPredicate *inPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"attribute IN %@", aCollection];
```

and that attribute has unique values, is it right to assume the order in which the results are returned corresponds with the order of the values in the collection, or would I need to sort them afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to sort them with an `NSSortDescriptor`.

If you want to sort by the order of your IN collection, follow the pattern described in [Core Data (SQLite backed) custom sorting of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393278/core-data-sqlite-backed-custom-sorting-of-strings), but add an Integer property instead of a Boolean, and make the Integer values correspond to the index of your collection.  Then create an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort by this custom property.

If more complex sorting is needed, you can put CoreData aside and sort the fetchedObjects array using `[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]`.

Comment: Can you make a sort descriptor that sorts according to the order in the collection used in the IN statement?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393278/core-data-sqlite-backed-custom-sorting-of-strings.  By adding a custom property to your NSManagedObject, make it an integer, with values corresponding to your collation (i.e. first in collection = 1, 2nd collection = 2).

Comment: but I have multiple collections with different orderings, so it's not singular property that can be assigned to the NSManagedObject.

Comment: edited answer, this custom property concept should get you closer.  If you have multiple collections, you might need multiple integer properties just for the purpose of sorting.  You could also do your sorting outside of CoreData by writing your own sort routine on the fetchedObjects array.